# IQ to RF conversion

Tags: signal-analysis, image-processing

I appreciate any help: 
 I wanna convert **IQ data to its RF data**, representing an image. The centre frequency and sampling rate are available. What I do is:

First I do up-sampling in MATLAB by applying interpolation along the depth.
So, the new data has a new sampling frequency higher than the first one.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to do low-pass filtering before multiplying the data by the exponential term (that converts IQ to RF)?
2. What is the exponential form that I need to multiply the IQ data by ( specifically, I am asking about the frequency or frequency ratio in the exponential term used to do the conversion, which I mentioned in the first question) Thanks

Could someone guide me through the detail one more time?
I read the documentation I copy here and it is confusing for me: (Page 8 and afterwards)

http://folk.ntnu.no/htorp/Undervisning/TTK10/IQdemodulation.pdf

Comment: Could you try to ask a precise question? Asking for a complete guide is not really appropriate for the format of this platform (which is pretty strictly Q&A).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Sure, My questions are: 
1) do I need to do low-pass filtering before multiplying the data by the exponential term (that converts IQ to RF)?
2) what is the exponential form that I need to multiply the IQ data by ( specifically, I am asking about the frequency or frequency ratio in the exponential term used to do the conversion, which I mentioned in first question)

Thanks,

Comment: hm, you're skipping steps if you're directly multiplying the IQ samples you get with a complex sinusoidal. Think about what the Nyquist bandwidth of these samples is!